# Raspberry pi camera module libavformat

Tags: python, linux, camera

I have a camera module connected to my raspberry pi and have followed these instructions to make it work for a stream:

[Installation guide](http://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-webcam-server/)

I type this command to test it:

```
./motion -n -c motion-mmalcam.conf
```

But I get this error :

```
./motion: error while loading shared libraries: libavformat.so.53: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And yes I have installed libjpeg62. The package for libavformat53 doesn't even exist. There seems to be no resolution to this problem.

EDIT: output for `ldd motion` Shows:

`libpq.so.5 => not found`

`libavformat.so.53 => not found`

`libavcodec.so.53 => not found`

`libavtil.so.51 => not found`

Comment: I found the solution here: there are a few steps but it worked. http://www.joakimlahtinen.se/2016/installing-motion-on-raspberry-pi-2-jessie/

Answer (score 2):

Try install this package:

```
sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev
```

More details about your problem you can find at: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=123397

Comment: Tried it but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `apt-cache search XXXX`, you can find which package the dependencies are included in.

For example:

```
apt-cache search libavformat
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and i used the command bellow:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Tell us what you've got!